# Installing Pygame (python 3.4) - windows 7 64 bit

Tags: pygame, windows64

I seem to be having problems installing pygame. I found the unofficial binary's from idf.uci.edu but they are whl files and i have no ways of extracting such files. 
Can somebody link me to a .exe file or tell me how to extract a whl file

Thanks

Comment: A quick google search shows that a ".whl" is a wheel file, which is in fact just a zip with some predefined package contents.   You could search how to install a wheel package or alternatively, try unzipping the file and use it directly without installing to your normal python install path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution

1) 7zip unzips the whl file. Place pygame folder  in the lib folder

2) Alternatively place the whl file in the scripts folder. From command line navigate to the scripts folder and run "pip install and the file name" press enter and away it installs

test)
type import pygame in idle - no errors, no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Guide to install .wlh: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels

The exe files: [pygame-1.9.2a0.win-amd64-py3.4.exe (onedrive)](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7E42B9EED122F59E!68180&authkey=!AMZvlN22mhfTffU&ithint=file%2cexe)